# Angular 2 - angular-cli pipe test with dependencies

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I'm trying to implement a test for a relatively isolated `Pipe`. I am using the latest version of `angular-cli` (with `@angular` 2.0.0).

The pipe code is:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DatePipe, JsonPipe } from "@angular/common";

@Pipe({name: 'dataTableFormat'})
export class DataTablePipe implements PipeTransform {

  // values with type 'json' are parsed to json. As a result, string values may be displayed with quotes ("<string>").
  // To avoid that, we remove these quotes with this regex
  private quotesExp: RegExp = /^\"|\"$/gi;

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe, private jsonPipe: JsonPipe) {
  }

  transform(value: string, type: string): string {
    switch (type) {
        case "date":
            return this.datePipe.transform(value, 'short');
        case "json":
            return this.jsonPipe.transform(value).replace(this.quotesExp, "");
        default:
            return value;
    }
  }
}
```

and the spec code is:

```
import {TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {DataTablePipe} from "./data-table.pipe";
import {DatePipe, JsonPipe} from "@angular/common";

describe('DataTableFormat', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ DataTablePipe ],
            providers: [
                DatePipe, JsonPipe
            ]
        });
    });

    it('sanity', () => {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should transform ', () => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataTablePipe);
        let comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        let testDate:Date = new Date();
        let datePipe = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DatePipe);

        expect(comp.transform(testDate.toString(), 'date')).toBe(datePipe.transform(testDate));

    });
});
```

sanity test passes, but the real test fails with the error:

```
    Error: Cannot create the component DataTablePipe as it was not imported into the testing module!
    at TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///Users/sninio/dev/csp-ui-ng/~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:1144:0 <- src/main/js/test.ts:6022:23)
    at Function.TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///Users/sninio/dev/csp-ui-ng/~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:972:0 <- src/main/js/test.ts:5850:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///Users/sninio/dev/csp-ui-ng/src/main/js/app/pages/+platform/events/data-table/data-table.pipe.spec.ts:23:30 <- src/main/js/test.ts:14770:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///Users/sninio/dev/csp-ui-ng/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:0 <- src/main/js/test.ts:26741:28)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///Users/sninio/dev/csp-ui-ng/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:72:0 <- src/main/js/test.ts:18285:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///Users/sninio/dev/csp-ui-ng/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:202:0 <- src/main/js/test.ts:26740:34)
    at Zone.run (webpack:///Users/sninio/dev/csp-ui-ng/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:0 <- src/main/js/test.ts:26634:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///Users/sninio/dev/csp-ui-ng/~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:91:27 <- src/main/js/test.ts:18021:50)
```

I'm sure it is some configuration that I missed, but for some reason the `DataTablePipe` is not imported into the testing module...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TestBed.createComponent` is strictly for creating components. What you can do though is inject the `DatePipe` and `JsonPipe` into the test. The just create you pipe from those

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

it('should transform ', inject([DatePipe, JsonPipe], (datePipe, jsonPipe) => {
  let pipe = new DataTablePipe(datePipe, jsonPipe);
  let testDate: Date = new Date();

  expect(pipe.transform(testDate.toString(), 'date'))
      .toBe(datePipe.transform(testDate, 'short'));
}));
```

Comment: This does not work, I am getting a missing provider error: Error: No provider for DatePipe! in src/main/js/test.ts

Comment: Worked fine for me when I tested. I used the exact code you posted. I just removed the `declarations` from the `TestBed`. Other than that, everything is the same, except for what I posted in my answer

Comment: Did you test it with angular-cli? I am sure it is some configuration I am missing

Comment: No I was using the angularclass webpack starter. Not really sure if that would make any difference. I don't see why it would for this simple case

Comment: Well what do you know??? When I switched the karma.conf to use `Chrome` instead of `PhantomJS` it now works!